# How to speed up the data fetching from oracle database to pentaho data integration?

Tags: oracle12c, pentaho-data-integration

I am using pentaho data integration 5.4.1.130 and Oracle 12c. I have successfully connected oracle database using ojdbc7.jar (using jre 1.7.0.51 for pentaho). But when I tried to preview a table from oracle database in transformation, I'm getting the below error.

Thanks in Advance.

Here's the log:

```
2017/04/18 17:15:49 - Version checker - OK
2017/04/18 18:16:53 - /Transformation 1 - Dispatching started for transformation [/Transformation 1]
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 - An error occurred executing SQL: 
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 - select * from "APPS"."PO_VENDORS";
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 - 
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1722)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.doQuery(TableInput.java:224)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.processRow(TableInput.java:138)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 - Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:202)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:45)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:766)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1244)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:420)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1711)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 -   ... 4 more
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - Table input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - /Transformation 1 - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2017/04/18 18:16:56 - /Transformation 1 - Transformation is killing the other steps!
```

Comment: Check the log properly. There's an error in your SQL syntax. Don't use the double quotes. If you have to use them, make sure you are using the case correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the log properly. There's an error in your SQL syntax. Don't use the double quotes. If you have to use them, make sure you are using the case correctly.

Putting double-quotes around an identifier in Oracle causes Oracle to treat the identifier as case sensitive rather than using the default of case-insensitivity. If you create a table (or a column) with double-quotes around the name, you must always refer to the identifier with double quotes and by correctly specifying the case (with the exception of all upper case identifiers, where double-quotes are meaningless).

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if it helped you. :)